Probability generating function to get the total of rolling 6 fair dice.
From Blitzstein and Hwang (2nd edition):

Let X be the total from rolling 6 fair dice, and let X1, . . . , X6 be the individual
rolls. What is P (X = 18)?


The PGF of X lets us count the cases in a systematic way. The PGF of X1 is
$$E(t^{X_1})=\frac{1}{6}(t+t^2+\dots+t^6).$$


Since the $X_j$ are i.i.d., the PGF of $X$ is $$E(t^X)=E(t^{X_1}\dots t^{X_6}) = E(t^{X_1})\dots E(t^{X_6}) = \frac{t^6}{6^6}(1+t+t^2+\dots+t^5)^6.$$

It turns out that the number of ways to get a sum of 18 is the coefficient of $t^{18}$ in $t^6(1+t+\dots+t^5)^6$, which is the coefficient of $t^{12}$ in $(1+t+\dots+t^5)^6$. To do this, we first manipulate it using the fact that it's a geometric series $$(1+t+\dots+t^5)^6 = \frac{(1-t^6)^6}{(1-t)^6}$$
To simplify the denominator further, they write $$\frac{1}{(1-t)^6}=(1+t+t^2\dots)^6=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kt^k.$$
I understand that the first equality $\frac{1}{(1-t)^6}=(1+t+t^2\dots)^6$ follows from the geometric series, but how do we get the last equality?

Not sure which equality is puzzling you.    You know that $\frac 1{1-t}=1+t+t^2+\cdots$, right?  Usual Geometric Series formula.

The second inequality follows from the binomial expansion of $(1-t)^{-6}$. Indeed, if you have a computer, expanding the $(1+t+\cdots+t^5)^6$ term is easy, but if you want to do it on exam, other method is required, so i guess thats why the book used binomial expansion here.

@lulu I meant how do they get from $(1+t+t^2\dots)^6=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kt^k$. Sorry if I was unclear.

That equation defines  the $a_k$.

The last equality just states that you could expand the sixth power of the geometric series in order to recover another series. It might be done explicitly with the help of the multinomial theorem, although some tedious manipulations with indices will have to be carried. Instead, you may begin with noticing that $\frac{\mathrm{d}^5}{\mathrm{d}t^5}\frac{1}{1-t} = \frac{5!}{(1-t)^6}$, hence
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{(1-t)^6} 
   &= \frac{1}{5!} \frac{\mathrm{d}^5}{\mathrm{d}t^5} \frac{1}{1-t} \\
   &= \frac{1}{5!} \frac{\mathrm{d}^5}{\mathrm{d}t^5} \sum_{k=0}^\infty t^k \\
   &= \frac{1}{5!} \sum_{k=\color{red}{5}}^\infty k(k-1)(k-2)(k-3)(k-4)t^{k-5} \\
   &= \frac{1}{5!} \sum_{k=0}^\infty (k+1)(k+2)(k+3)(k+4)(k+5)t^k \\
   &= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(k+5)!}{5!k!}t^k \\
\end{align}
$$
and finally $a_k = \binom{k+5}{5}$.
